# Transparent Technic elements

Tags: piece-information, technic, colour

I know these Technic liftarms come in clear transparent:

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32278#T=S&C=12

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32009#T=S&C=12

[image]

These liftarms come in a couple of transparent colors (not clear transparent):

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32348#T=S&C=15

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32449#T=S&C=15

[image]

Also this connector comes in transparent

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32016#T=S&C=12

[image]

And these connectors come in transparent red

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6538b#T=S&C=17

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32013#T=S&C=17

[image]

Are there any other liftarms, connectors or Technic elements in general that come in transparent colors?

Answer (score 1):

There are far more parts within Technic category in Transparent colors and just too many parts to list them all. I suggest checking [Color Guide](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp) on BrickLink, Transparent Colors section and pick first column (named Parts) Most of the colors have Technic bits in colors you are interested in.

For example, just [Trans-Clear](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&colorPart=12&v=3) color has 23 items under various Technic categories.